# Reduce page load time on simple .html file

Tags: html, web, page-load-time, server-response

I have sample html page with some basic content - https://autem-services.fr/prestation.html

But for a reason i don't know the page make more than 1s to be load - See picture
[image]

There are no largest file on it and all external link i place on  are few CND

- Google Analytics
- Font Awesome for icons

I also try to remove all page content and just put an h1 (with no links, no CDN, no Js Files)but still make long time to charge (sometime 24s sometime 1m20s sometime 700ms) - See picture
[image]

The same problem also occured on the home page: https://www.autem-services.fr

Any suggestions or advices to help me please?

Answer (score 0):

Your server is a little slow and you HELLO page was redirected.
You presentation link does not work so I checked you home page.
It could use some work
Looking at the waterfall the page does no begin to load until about 1.4 seconds.  It appears the page was redirected because the first two requests are the same, your index page.  Request #1 took 1 second and request #2 took about 0.5 seconds.
WebpageTest says time to first byte = 1.008S and start render = 2.830.
This means the Browser couldn't not start rendering until those 8 CSS and JS were first loaded.  Start render is the green vertical line at 2.8 seconds on the waterfall.
 Then it took about 1.1 seconds to load to where it was rendering the way you want.
The server is a big problem for you.  It is much too slow.  Especially with the redirect. Have someone fix that. Redirects are a bad thing.  
When I access the page from my PC in Tampa FL, the first response (the response header) took about 250 milliseconds. I do not like the way the screen shakes as I scroll down.  That's poor design.
 But 250 mS is not bad. But I want to see a small page completely loaded in that time frame.  I consider any thing over 0.5 sec. to long.
  The server itself is not horrible.  The way it is be used is the problem.  What is the server is doing other than immediately returning the response header. It is doing something else.
I do not like to see images in the HTML without the width and height specified.  It gives the Browser too much unnecessary work to do and may be responsible for the shaky scroll. 
The big thing slowing down the load time is the CSS and JS. You should fix the few HTML errors. 
Anything else?  You did not ask a specific question.

[image]

[image]